# Click not firing first time after rebind with live() method

Tags: drupal-views, toggle, jquery

I understand that this is a probably a  noob-ish question, but I've had no luck with the other threads I've found on the same topic.

I've devised a workaround to hack a views exposed filter to hide and show products with a stock count of "0". The exposed filter for the stock count (input#edit-stock) is hidden with CSS and inside a custom block is a link to manipulate the form and trigger the query (with ajax). This is working great, but with one exception -  after resetting the form with the views-provided "reset" button, toggle() will not rebind properly to the link, and click won't fire the first time. Works fine on the 2nd click. I'm sure that the solution is very simple, but I'm at a loss..

How to rebind toggle() effectively?

Sorry, I'm unable to provide a live example. Many thanks for any input.

CUSTOM BLOCK:

```
    <a id="toggle" href="#">exclude</a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {        

    var include = function () { 
        $('input#edit-stock').attr('value', 0).submit();
        $('a#toggle').html('include');
    }; 

    var exclude = function () {
        $('input#edit-stock').attr('value', '').submit();
        $('a#toggle').html('exclude');
    }; 


    $('a#toggle').toggle(include, exclude);


    $('input#edit-reset').live('click', function (event) {
      $('a#toggle').unbind('toggle').toggle(include, exclude).html('exclude');
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i get the problem right you need to reset the toggle. Why instead of unbind toggle and rebinding it you just don't simulate a click if the link is == to include?

```
$(document).ready(function () {        

    var include = function () { 
        $('input#edit-stock').attr('value', 0).submit();
        $('a#toggle').html('include');
    }; 

    var exclude = function () {
        $('input#edit-stock').attr('value', '').submit();
        $('a#toggle').html('exclude');
    }; 


    $('a#toggle').toggle(include, exclude);


    $('input#edit-reset').live('click', function (event) {
        //if the link is include, click it so that it resets to exclude, else do nothing
        if ($('a#toggle').html() == 'include'){
            $('a#toggle').click();
        }
    });


});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PSLBb/

(Hope this is what you were looking for)

Comment: AH..yes, that's perfect! I had been trying something similar but must've overlooked something. Thanks so much!